# UIcollection view showing the images stacked in a single view

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage

One of my `storyboard` has a table view cell which calls the collection view defined in the separate scene. Collection view includes a UIImage view with a page control till ios 10 each of the images used to display fully within the imageview after the upgrade all the images are showing up as stacked on one another as in the attached image.once i click on this stacked image everything becomes proper until i revisit the storyboard. Is there anything which changed with respect to UIImage or collectionview in the new upgrade?

The same code works fine in ipod.

[image: UIImageview showing multiple images]

Code Sample:

```
#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return collectionView.bounds.size;
}
```

Is it something to do with pagecontrol being used??

Answer (score 1):

I hope you would have used `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` for specifying collection view cell size previously and would have added `UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate` delegate methods.

Now for iOS 10 we need to add `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` delegate, only then `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` will be executed.

Try it I hope it will fix your issue.

Comment: I am using the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout delegate in my code,  please have a look at the code sample provided above.

Comment: Ok, as per the code given you are setting the cell size to collection view size to display the image in full screen. And you said it works fine when you click on any cell right ? If its so then may I know what have you done in didSelectItemAtIndexPath ?

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly providing the height and width of `collectionView.bounds.size`